# Tree conflict on new unmodified branches

Tags: svn

I've found myself with a problem I connot seem to solve at this moment.

I created a new repository with in the trunk the leading copy of my project. 
Then i create a branch from the working copy and do a fresh checkout of the branch in a new local working copy. (EDITED)

While not having made a change in the trunk or the branch I get tree conflicts in all the main folders in the project while merging trunk:head rivision to the branch.

So advice would be welcome regarding this, I was thinking of removing the repository completely and create a new one to see if this "error" persists. however a cleaner solution would be welcome.

BTW even after solving the conflict with keeping local or keeping from repository will result in the same conflicts if i do another merge.

Folder structure is basic:

- /repos/project/trunk
- /repos/project/tags
- /repos/project/branches/project_branch1
- /repos/project/branches/project_branch2

When doing the merge. both trunk and branch are at the same repository version.

Step by Step :

1. I create the project svn with svnadmin create project
2. Create 3 folders one by one (revision is 3)
3. i do a checkout of the trunk.
4. Add all project files in the folder add/commit
5. Create a branch from trunk in branches folder branches/project_branch_1
6. i do a checkout of the branch
7. update both trunk and branch. their versions get updated to the latest (5)
8. do a merge ifrom trunk:head to branch -> tree conflicts apear.

Comment: Could you describe your repository structure? (how you setup trunk, branch folders, if you did)

Comment: /repos/project/trunk , /repos/project/branches/sub_project1, /repos/project/branches/sub_project2, /repos/project/tags

Comment: Did you create the branch from the trunk url or from the trunk checkout? (If from the checkout: make sure you update before tagging)

Comment: yep everything was going by the book, the problem was the outdates subversion running on my server. which i forgot to update after a complete reinstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tree conflicts appear when a merge brings in new directory / files that are already in the source location.  Most likely problem is that the arguments to the merge command are not correct and the SVN client is attempting to re-add the files into your working copy.  How are you performing the merge (step 8)? Also, if you are using an older version of SVN server (1.4) it does not perform merge tracking and that also may contribute the errors you are seeing.

Comment: hmm, currently at my work, will check the svnserver once i get home, you might be right about not having an uptodate version of svn on the server

Comment: the version was actually the problem, an update to subversion 1.6 was the fix